# Website connection timeout

Tags: apache2, performance, log

I have 2 websites hosted on a virtual root server (ubuntu) that are not reachable anymore (timeout on both domains). Nothing was changed on the server and no new feature was deployed for both websites.

I checked the RAM and CPU usage, everything seems ok.
I checked apache error log and syslog, nothing either ...

This happened suddenly and I don't know how to fix it. Any idea ?

Comment: If there's nothing in the Apache log that suggests a problem with the HTTP server process and there's nothing in t he access log, this would suggest that your HTTP request never reaches the server process. My first thought at this point is to check if there might be a firewall issue that prevents your HTTP request from reaching the server process.

Comment: I checked the access.log and nothing comes up when I try to reach the website so you may be right. You mean a Firewall on the server ? How do I check that ? I have tried to access the websites from different computers and it doesnt work

Comment: Almost certainly you're running iptables. A reasonably easy way to manage iptables is ufw (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) which is a front-end for iptables. In turn there's a graphical front end for ufw called gufw. The log output from iptables is generated by the kernel, so it goes into /var/log/kern.log. I'd start there. :)